# am getting undefined while trying execute following code

Tags: reactjs

TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

getting this error, please help me.

Am trying to check and uncheck the checkbox when onchange event occures

please find the code here
https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-mendeleev-cd881

Comment: update handleChange to `handleChange={() => this.handleChange}`

Comment: Thnak you Nicolae. your solution helped me to get rid of that error. But when i click that check box there is no action as expected, can you please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

In render you should make sure declare as a function [updated code](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-leftpad-yeq38)

Answer (score 0):

Becauuse `this` in the loop will change the context of the current object.

Assign `this` to another variable and use that variable instead.

`self` in this case:

[See solution here](https://pocketmath.atlassian.net/browse/PM-9519)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a constant referencing `this` inside your render like so:

```
import React from "react";
import todosData from "./TodoData";
import ToDoItems from "./ToDoItems";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updateTodo = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        }
        return todo;
      });
      return {
        todos: updateTodo
      };
    });
  }
  render() {
    const that = this;
    const todoData = this.state.todos.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <ToDoItems key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={that.handleChange} />
      );
    });
    return <div>{todoData}</div>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Typo in **ToDoItems.js** - `props.handlehange`
2. You need to assign `this` to a variable because of different context in `map` 
   function
3. Pass `item.id` in `handleChange()` function to keep track of your todo item.

   Here is updated [solution](https://codesandbox.io/embed/reacttodo-m4sun?fontsize=14).